# PHP printer not printing on a new line

Tags: php, printing, thermal-printer

I'm attaching a **80 mm thermal printer** to my windows server, it's working great but when the text is longer than the page width the rest of the text disappears instead of moving it to the next line automatically. here's my code

```
$handle = printer_open("POS"); 
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_FORMAT, PRINTER_FORMAT_CUSTOM);
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_WIDTH, "80");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 40, 30, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
printer_draw_text($handle, $lipsum, 10, 10);
printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but try removing the quotes around the 80, such as `printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_WIDTH, 80);` - since seeing the manual on this http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.printer-set-option.php one of the options shows integers without quotes `printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_SCALE, 75);` give that a whirl.

Comment: `$handle = printer_open("POS");` make sure you selected the correct printer for this and its onboard options and in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this: 

$handle = printer_open("POS"); 
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_FORMAT, PRINTER_FORMAT_CUSTOM);
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_WIDTH, "80");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 40, 30, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);



printer_draw_text($handle, 'TEST 1', 10, 10);
printer_draw_text($handle, 'TEST 2', 10, 40);
printer_draw_text($handle, 'TEST 3', 10, 70);



printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
```